# Как создать атрибут XAttribute без префиксов пространства имен?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
XElement parent = /* некий код */;
XName name = XName.Get("Content", parent.Name.NamespaceName);
XAttribute att = new XAttribute(name, "Value");
parent.Add(att);
MessageBox.Show(att.ToString());
```

Выводит

```
p0:Content="Value"
```

Как избавиться от префикса `p0` ?
Из-за него в `parent` пространство имен дублируется и `SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces` не помогает, так как префиксы разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос, хотя у меня возник другой.

[image: Первый конструктор]

[image: Второй конструктор]

Как видим Visual Studio 2013 показывает, что конструкторов только 2. Однако следующий код вполне работает:

```
XAttribute att = new XAttribute("Content", "Value");
MessageBox.Show(att.ToString());
```

Выводит 
`Content="Value"` и уже нормально добавляется в родителя.

В чем тут фишка с конструкторами я не понимаю.

Comment: Дело в том, что строка имплицитно конвертируется в `XName`.

Comment: @VladD да действительно `XName name3 = "dd";` работает. А такие возможности как-то заранее узнать можно?

Comment: Ну, я увидел пример кода со строкой, сравнил с сигнатурой конструктора, почесал голову и пошёл выяснять, почему :-) То есть заранее, судя по всему, нет.

Comment: В принципе, в документации есть [оператор неявной конверсии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.op_implicit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), но кто ж туда заглядывает?

Comment: Там ещё и пример про namespace в фигурных скобках.

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на свой вопрос - поделитесь им здесь. а новый вопрос оформите как новый вопрос.

Comment: @PashaPash ответ на свой вопрос я уже написал, а на новый VladD также ответил.